# Remove material top tabs header from specific screen react navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a nested navigators, NativeStack -> MatTopTabStack (as per documentation), so when I navigate to a screen, an empty space appears which from the size of it looks like top tabs section, but is invisible... below is the code and some screenshot...

[image]
[image]

Relevant Code:

```js
const topTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const MatTopStack = () => {
    return (
        <topTab.Navigator>
            <topTab.Screen name="General" component={General} />
            <topTab.Screen name="Subscribed" component={Subscribed} />
        </topTab.Navigator>
    );
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const MainStack = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="MatTopStack"
            screenOptions={{
                headerTitle: 'MYAPP',
                headerRight: () => <Text>Logout</Text>,
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="MatTopStack" component={MatTopStack} />
            <Stack.Screen
                options={{ header: () => null }}
                name="StrategyDetails"
                component={StrategyDetails}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Now, In strategy details screen, I want to show a custom header, but it is not working as I'm getting that empty space in between...

```js
const StrategyDetails = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            header: () => (
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text><--</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text>{data.strategyName}</Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text>BUY</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            ),
        });
    }, [data]);
    
    return (
        ...
    );

}
```

How can I get rid of that empty space in `StrategyDetails` screen as I'm dealing with nested navigators...

Comment: Have you already tried setting ```headerShown: false``` instead of setting header to null? Here are more header related options for the screen
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown

Comment: @sushrut619 Yes I did, it removes the header totally, hence `navigation.setOptions` is of no use then...